# NSF font research.gov

Tags: fonts

I have submitted U.S. National Science Foundation (NSF) proposals with PDF files created using:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathptmx}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

before on `fastlane` with success.

However, I am now forced to upload to `research.gov` and I get a warning when I upload the PDF that my font does not meet the standard.

Anyone have this or have some workaround or other font (besides the default as it is huge)?

Comment: Welcome to the community of TeX.SE. What is NSF? I have not understood, for example, your question. Please can you put a minimal example in LaTeX to understand your problem?

Comment: National Science Foundation (NSF)

Comment: https://blog.researchadmin.asu.edu/nsf-research-gov-updates-pdf-upload-font-options/

Comment: @ScottSeidman The 2019 GPG (p. II-3) states 11pt or larger for Times not 10pt. But this isn't the question. The issue is that the document check throws a warning, because it doesn't find Times New Roman since `mathptmx` is a clone.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Reading your link more fully it acknowledges that this information differs from the GPG. Go figure.

Comment: Also, computer modern should be fine, so tweakjngvthe default size might be enough.

Comment: @ScottSeidman The size difference between Computer Modern and Times New Roman is substantial. 15 pages of 11pt CM comes out at a little under 14 pages of Times New Roman. Given the page restrictions on NSF grants, I would not recommend CM as the font.

Comment: @AlanMunn I agree.  Size is an issue with the page format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LaTeX Times fonts (`mathptmx`, or better, the newer `txmath` and `txtext` fonts) are clones of Times New Roman. My experience (as your earlier experience is) is that this is an acceptable font. I have not submitted an NSF grant through Grants.gov recently enough to know if you will be rejected.

If you will be rejected using the Times clones (because the system is simply trained to look at the font names in the document), then the safest solution is to use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX and use Times New Roman as the font (assuming you have it on your system.)  The change from your existing document isn't very substantial. Instead of

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

you can use

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
```

The `newtxmath` math fonts are a better version of `mathptmx`. Since the system allows the use of other fonts for math or special symbols/languages the presence of Times New Roman as the main text font should suffice to allow it to pass.

Alternatively, you could use `unicode-math` and the STIX math font:

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont[]{Stix Two Math}
\setmathfont[range=\mathit/{latin,Latin,greek,Greek}]{xits-math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

Comment: Thanks! Yes, it seems that they are now (on `research.gov`) just checking the metadata and not recompiling as they did on fastline, so you get a warning.  Normally I would ignore the warning, but my OSP is being very picky and reuploading everything before submission (so they would yell at me).  What is funny is that if I took it with `mathptmx` adobe DC will export it to Times New Roman with no problem (though it cannot do `sparklines` and some latex generated graphs right).  I ended up using LuaLatex with your code and it worked great! But  `mathptmx` still looks better than `LuaLatex` .

Comment: @user1978271 This is useful information to know (and sad), but the shift to `research.gov` from Fastlane is also sad. I'm surprised about your second comment. You shouldn't notice any major difference between your two documents, and if anything the `xits` math font should be more consistent than `mathptmx`.

Comment: @user1978271 Please note edit on the math setup. I had `math-style=upright` which is probably not appropriate for general math use. I've removed it.

Comment: Yes `xits` math font is better.  I normally don't worry too much about math font and figures, because no matter what you are more than likely going to throw a font size warning for a subscript or something. I think everyone is used to that by now.

Comment: Yes the shift to `research.gov` is sad.  From reading all the lit, it looks like they just added the font checkers (June 2020-- I think they updated it) for pdf from latex.  Maybe they will update it again so it is not so picky.

Comment: @user1978271 There's now an official version of the Stix fonts, so I've updated the answer to reflect that.